# Laravel Auth Duplicate Emails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel Auth to allow people to sign in.

Now I have a database in which people can exist multiple times ( for newer events )

### So i'm wondering if it's possible to adjust the Auth Query to check for the latest email addresses, So fetch the email and password combination with the highest ID in the db

I don't seem to find the Query anywhere in the Illuminate Structure.. Am i looking in the wrong place here?

```
Class guard {
```

Seems to have the functionality of logging people in.
Thank you!

Comment: That's a very bad db design, make email unique and create forgot password as backup plan

Comment: I know it's an unexepected thing as there can now be multiple events that the same people can join, so it's to late to change database i'm affraid.. #customerheadaches

Comment: Create an event-customer mapped table consisting of customer_id and event_id

Comment: How could this help me with Auth? ( thank for your time btw )

Comment: So, there will be 3 table customer, event, and customer-event table and by that you can establish one-to-many relation (i.e. 1 user can attend 1 or more event) and you will have unique column for email by that you don't have to alter Auth validate functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can by overriding the Auth driver.

To create a custom driver:
 1. Create a new class that implements `UserProviderInterface`
 2. Register your auth driver in `app/start/global.php` add the following:

```
Auth::extend('auth.mydriver', function($app)
{
    return new MyApp\Extensions\MyAuthDriver;
});
```

3. Tell config to look for your driver in `app/config/auth.php` and change `'driver' => 'auth.mydriver',`

Now Laravel uses your implementation of Auth. to get started I would copy the original code and change the methods you want to give a custom implementation

EDIT:

If you look at how attempt work it calls retrieveByCredentials if normal validation fails. 
If you want to override the way Guard you'll have to create your own Guard class and use instead of default one (`app/config/app.php`)

```
/**
     * Attempt to authenticate a user using the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @param  bool   $remember
     * @param  bool   $login
     * @return bool
     */
    public function attempt(array $credentials = array(), $remember = false, $login = true)
    {
        $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember, $login);
        $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);
        // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
        // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
        // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
        if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials))
        {
            if ($login) $this->login($user, $remember);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response, What code is the original code? the whole code from the Guard class? Thanks!

Comment: The original file can be found in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php`.(can you accept the answer if it helped)

Comment: Well your answer gave me a good insight, But i don't see the query anywhere in that EloquentUserProvider.php file that I can modify..

Comment: Thank you! So is it possible to check there for a way of getting the highest id for the giving password? Because a email address wil exists multiple times in the database, I need the last entry. Thanks!

Comment: You do something like `$q = $model->newQuery(); $q->whereEmail($email)->last()`this will give you what you need. then you return this record and it will be validated

Comment: Hmh, thanks again! but i can't seem to find out where to place this code? In the Guard.php?

Comment: you don't change your any code in vendor folder, change it inside the `MyAuthDriver` retrieveByCredentials